# What are other ways to put an accent color on the main image?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do a challenge from Frontend Mentor and I'm wondering what are other ways to put the accent color on the main image? I want to explore different ways to style an image, let me know if you have any suggestions.

```
  .container .picture {
    background: url("./images/image-header-mobile.jpg") no-repeat center/cover;
    height: 400px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  }
  
  .container .picture .overlay { /*accent color of the image*/ 
    background-color: hsla(277, 64%, 61%, 0.7); 
    height: 400px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Outline on a simple image can do the trick:

```css
img {
  outline: 100vmax solid hsla(277, 64%, 61%, 0.7);
  outline-offset: -100vmax;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(#000 0 0); /* to hide the overflowing outline */
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1069/200/200">
```